# Python requests.get doesn't seem to get the correct data

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to use an API on urlscan.io in order to grab a screenshot of a website. I'm doing this by grabbing the uuid from a post request to the website then using uuid to form a url within a get request.

**url = "urlscan.io/screenshots/" + str(response_json) + ".png"** looks to be the issue but if I hardcoded the UUID instead of using str(response_json) then this will work.

The below code using str(response_json) will get a screenshot from the url but an incorrect one (it looks to be a generic unable to get screenshot png.) example can be found here https://urlscan.io/screenshots/69d42b71-ac0c-4d14-a046-0282374efa5.png. This will create a png image on my PC but just of the no screenshot available png.

The print result is as follows: https://urlscan.io/screenshots/69d42b71-ac0c-4d14-a046-02182374efa5.png which is what I'm wanting to download onto the pc from this code.

It's as if the str(response_json) isn't working in the get request but I can't figure out why.

````
  data = {"url": phishing_url, "visibility": "public"}
  response = requests.post('https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/',headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
  response_json = response.json()['uuid']
  url = "https://urlscan.io/screenshots/" + str(response_json) + ".png"
  response_image = requests.get(url)
  print("https://urlscan.io/screenshots/" + response_json + ".png")

  # This will create the screenshot so you can manually verify malicious content 

  file = open(phishing_url + ".png", "wb")
  file.write(response_image.content)
  file.close()```
````

Comment: Can you include the output of the print statement? Like you said, it's possible `str(response_json)` is not returning what you think it should.

Comment: Apologies, that would have been helpful!

The print result is as follows: https://urlscan.io/screenshots/69d42b71-ac0c-4d14-a046-02182374efa5.png 

That's the correct format I need and works when I manually enter that link into a browser.

Comment: Can you edit the question to elaborate on *what* isn't working then? Does the program throw an error, does the file not write, is the written file not readable by image viewing software? Right now anyone trying to answer can only guess.

Comment: Hopefully, I've edited a bit more better now.

Comment: looking at the API docs https://urlscan.io/docs/api/#result - it seems you should wait for the request to be processed by polling `https://urlscan.io/api/v1/result/$uuid/` until it returns a 200 status code.  Your code looks like it expects the results / screenshot to be available immediately after the scan request is sent.

Comment: That would make sense - thank you!